# maxscale 2.1 upgrade breaks client authentication

Tags: mysql-replication, mariadb

upgrading from maxscale from maxscale-2.0.1-1.x86_64 to maxscale-2.1.13-1.x86_64 causes my replication user to no longer authorize. I've verified the grants are correct and blew away the cache dir, to no avail. When I downgrade to the previous version I'm able to connect as expected.

I also confirmed the grant is loaded in the dbusers.db cache file upon upgrade. I also confirmed that these grants work when connecting directly to the source/master database.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you had a working setup which broke when you upgraded MaxScale, I would say that this is a bug. Nevertheless, double-checking that authentication works is never a bad idea.

1. Check whether you can connect to the backend database server from the MaxScale host. If this works, the MaxScale side of the grants are OK.
2. Do the same on the client host. If this works, you know that authentication in MaxScale should work.
3. Execute the [SQL listed on the MaxScale troubleshooting wiki page](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/MaxScale/wiki/Troubleshooting). Check that it returns the users you expect to see.

If upgrading to a newer version causes problems and a downgrade solves them, it's definitely not expected behavior. I would recommend reporting this as a bug. The MaxScale bug tracker is in the [MariaDB Jira under the MaxScale project](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS). Remember to attach any relevant configuration files, the environment where you observed the problem and (if possible) how to reproduce it.